# mysql docker image support multiply databases creation at start

Tags: mysql, docker, percona

I need to have to database created at startup in one service. F.e.:
services:

```
  db:
    image: percona:5.7.24-centos
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
      MYSQL_DATABASE_1: db2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    network_mode: "host"
```

But unfortunatelly only one is supported using image/environment variable: `MYSQL_DATABASE`.

I am using this in docker-compose

Can I ask for help?

Comment: Maybe write your own Dockerfile and copy the sql script which will create a new database onto the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So write your own Dockerfile and copy the sql script which will create a new database onto the image.
Something like below

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \

ADD yourscript.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ 

EXPOSE 3306
```

So all the scipts inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` will be executed at container startup. In effect, your second database creation script would go inside `yourscript.sql` which will be executed on container startup

You can build the image using the command
`docker build -t masterdanny/percona:5.7.24-centos`

and then use that new image in your docker-compose file

Cheers. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How can I make those scripts to be executed as a root? Default user for this dokerfile is mysql.

Comment: the sql script is downloaded from nexus in my case, I need to save it somewhere. But I am mysql user without home directory :(
there is no sudo command also

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the sql file is coming from. You can copy it from your local or you can download it from your nexus. All this goes in the dockerfile. mysql will be able to exectue it if you put it in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ ` directory.